# Conceptual understanding: matching series representation with the Laurent expansion.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

*DISCLAIMER*: *I am a highschool student who isn't good at math, some of my questions may be trivial in which case I apologise.*

In the Laurent expansion of a function, where is the correspondence between $a_n, b_n$ and the positive and negative power series? I understand that the series representations reduce to just taylor series when the Laurent series is analytic within circle centered at $z_0$.

But why is it that even when a function is only analytic in an annular domain, it may possibly still only have a positive or a negative series representation and not both?  $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}$$

---

**Example one**

In Complex variables and Applications (9th). the book remarks on the series representation of $e^{1/z}$ for $|z|>0$.
$$e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^n}$$
*Quote: "No positive powers of $z$ appear here, since the coefficients of positive powers are zero."*

I understand the uniqueness of representations but why do the positive powers just disappear?

What are they ($a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$) in the first place and why are they zero?

---

**Example two**

Consider the expansion within $|z-1|>2$ of $$f(z)=\frac{2z-4}{z^2-4z+3}$$
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-3}+\frac{1}{z-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z-1}}\right)+\frac{1}{z-1} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2^n}{(z-1)^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{z-1}
\end{align}

Where are the positive powers $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ ?

Comment: You say "But why is it that even when a function is only analytic in an annular domain, it may still only have a positive or a negative series representation and not both?" This isn't in general true. Look at $z+\frac{1}{z}$ on $0<|z|<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the exponential function I'm not sure I understand your question as it is basically the definition of the function itself. As "weird" as it could seems to you I don't understand why we should need positive powers. For the $a_{n}$ they are strictly related to the Cauchy formula.[A very "personal" note, i would suggest you to dig more in they integral form before and then go into series representation, while there is not a real "correct" order in which form to study before i found it much more easy to grasp when i first encountered this topics] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)